# Jquery iterate through the parent table on click of a link within a child td

Tags: jquery

I have the following table structure

```
<table calss="ptable">
<tr>
<td><select>...</select></td>
<td><input/></td>
<td>input/></td>
<td><a class="abc"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select>...</select></td>
<td><input/></td>
<td>input/></td>
<td><a class="abc"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select>...</select></td>
<td><input/></td>
<td>input/></td>
<td><a class="abc"></a></td>    </tr></table>
```

now on click of 'a' tag I have to iterate through the whole table and set vales for select and input within each td. I m Using jquery... Please help I m new to jquery....

I found solution for this like .......

```
  var firsta = $(".abc").first().parents(".ptable");              
  $(firsta).children("tbody").find("tr td").each(function (index) { alert(index); });
```

Is there a better way to achive this.

Comment: Which values do you want to set? Especially: do they depend on the index of the td-tags, such that in the first td-tag there is written someting like "1. td"?

Comment: look into the `.parent()` function and the `siblings()` function. Basically you need to navigate up the dom until you get to the tr, and then grab all of that tr's siblings-- i.e. all of the rest of the trs in the table. Once you have all of the trs you can iterate their `children()` to look at all of the tds.

Comment: @Axel Thanks for the help.... no they do not depend on td..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don"t want to keep it unanswered. as I have one solution I would like to share it...

```
  var firsta = $(".abc").first().parents(".ptable");              
  $(firsta).children("tbody").find("tr td").each(function (index) { alert(index); });
```

Thanks everyone for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

```
function event_a() {
    $(".ptable").find("td").bind("click",{nr:index},function(evt){
        alert(evt.data.nr);
    });
}
```

You can bind this function to each a-tag by:

```
$(".abc a").click(event_a);
```

Comment: @Alex Iteration through the table is my concern.

Comment: @Yagnesh.Dixit: I changed my code. I am not really sure, if You want to bind an event to each td oder if You want to change the Html within each td-tag. My code binds an event. (At least it should).

Comment: Thanks @Alex but I dont want to bind any click event to any element its already there and is working fine I just want to loop through the table and set the values for select and input in my first and second td of each tr in the click event of my a tag.. .... Hope this clears your confusion...

Comment: Perhaps it would help, if you give an example which values in detail should be set.